# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fsevents', Can't resolve 'uglify-js',Can't resolve '@swc/core',Can't resolve '@babel/preset-typescript/package.json'

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13

Module not found: Can't resolve 'uglify-js'
Module not found: Can't resolve '@swc/core'
Module not found: Can't resolve 'esbuild'
Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/preset-typescript/package.json'
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

As I attempted to deploy my Next.js 14 project on Vercel, I encountered the mentioned errors. I initially tried uninstalling node_modules and package-lock.json, also downgraded the nextjs version to 13.4.19, but the errors persisted. Later, I realized that the errors started occurring after installing the next-pwa package. And in final I'm using windows 10 machine